# 1.5V "amplified ear" debugging

Tags: transistors, audio, amplifier, dc, low-voltage

I've tried to make this circuit, a [1.5V audio amplifier](http://www.redcircuits.com/Page38.htm).

I've omitted P1 and directly connected C6 to C3 as stated in the page.

I've also omitted the switch SW1 and connected a wire for the path represented by the dashed line(ganging?)
Is this the right thing to do?

Since I can't afford a CRO, what is the next best thing I can do to debug this circuit. 
Any help appreciable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In omitting P1 (22k variable) substitute a 22k fixed resistor in its place.This will set the amplifier at its highest gain. If it is too loud you can reduce the volume with a simple potential divider made from two fixed resistors that add up to 22k (e.g. 11k + 11K) taking C6 to the junction between them.

SW1 is the ON/OFF switch. Without it the batteries will run down as there is no way to switch the circuit off. So not a good idea to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The dashed line indicates that P1 and SW1 are physically connected - like the combined power switch and volume control on older radios.

Since you've omitted P1, you either use a simple SPST switch in place of SW1, or connect the juntion of R8 and the top lead of the jack directly to the battery + terminal.

From your description, I don't think you have any power to the circuit, so it won't work.

Comment: sorry, my bad:-P Forgot to mention that I'm using a AA cell..
Since I'm not using a pot, I don't need to connect the junction of C3-C6 to the battery right?

Answer (score 2):

C6-C3 junction is never connected to the + of the battery, the dashed line indicates mechanical coupling of the switch and pot. Not an electrical connection.